# Can I delete array element by element?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create custom list. This is the node structure:

```
struct Node {
    ListNode* prev;
    ListNode* next;
    void* data;
};
```

One of constructors creates list from array. So I decided to allocate nodes in consecutive part of memory to make algorithm a little bit faster.

```
auto elements = new Node[size];
elements[0] = ...
elements[size - 1] = ...
for (int i = 1; i + 1 < size; i++) {
    elements[i].data = array[i];
    elements[i].prev = &elements[i - 1];
    elements[i].next = &elements[i + 1];
}
head = &elements[0];
tail = &elements[size - 1];
```

After that I can add new elements:

```
Node* tmp = new Node;
tmp->prev = tail;
tmp->data = data;
tail = tmp;
```

Also I can change `next` and `prev`.

So I can't distinguish elements(is this element part of array or have been allocated later using `new`) and in destructor I have to delete elements using `delete` instead of `delete[]`.

```
Node* curNode = head;
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    Node* tmp = curNode.next;
    delete curNode;
    curNode = tmp;
}
```

This code doesn't delete elements which have been allocated in array(according to Valgrind).
How can I allocate nodes in one array(to decrease number of cache misses) and then successfully delete them element by element?

Comment: The answer is really "any way you want". There's no one right way. Probably the most obvious way is to construct an object that allocates one large chunk and whose destructor decrements the "use count" on the block, only freeing the block when its use count gets to zero. But generally, I just wouldn't bother. I'm not convinced you'll get any performance benefit out of the effort.

Comment: once you decided to allocate them in a chunk you should consider `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of bothering about manual `new` and `delete`

Comment: You must not call `delete` on anything you did not get from `new`. If you bulk-allocate your objects, you cannot `delete` the individual object, only the entire collection.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use row pointers

Comment: @NikitaMescheryackov It looks like you are trying to create a linked list, but also creating a dynamic array at the same time.  Which data structure are you supposed to implement?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I'm trying to create linked list from array. This structure can add new nodes to the end, delete and change next and prev pointers like List

Comment: The way linked lists are done using arrays is that the `next` and `previous` are actually integers denoting the index of the next and previous items.   Deleted entries are marked as deleted, not really deleted, so that if a new entry comes along, it takes over that location.  If you read data structures books from a long time ago, that's how they were done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie My implementation doesn't base on array. AddElement function makes node using new. I use an array just to be sure that elements in the beginning placed sequentially.

Comment: So what are `next` and `prev` pointing to?  If it's elements within the array, how do you propose expanding this array?  When you do that, you are invalidating all the addresses, thus the list has to be rebuilt.  In addition to that, you can't simply delete single items using `delete`.  Maybe this where you made your mistake, and that is misunderstanding what `delete` does.

Comment: *My implementation doesn't base on array* -- Yes it does, you just didn't realize it when you did `auto elements = new [Size];`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I don't need to expand array I just make `tail = new Node`.In the end, when I delete list some of elements are part of array and some allocated using `new` instead of `new[]` , so I can't distinguish them in destructor and have to use `delete`.

Comment: `auto elements = new Node[size];` -- You already allocated `size` Nodes here.  What is this extra `new` you're talking about?   The nodes are already created, and you're adjusting the `next` and `prev` pointers of those items in the array.   But the bottom line is this -- your code showing `delete` cannot be done.  If you want to avoid cache misses, then a linked list is not the data structure you would use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is the most hacky implementation of linked list you can possibly think of. For all real life purpose you should stick with `STL` and it looks like `std::vector` does what you want. That being said, if you are trying to implement your own linked list to learn how it works, let me start by saying that you are already doing it wrong.

By definition linked list is made out of `Nodes` where each `Node` points to the `next` one and can also point to `previous`. Physical order of individual nodes in memory plays no role and is irrelevant from functionality point of view. There is potential performance gain related do `cache hits` if you have bunch of consecutive `Nodes` in the same page, but it is not something you should be aiming at when implementing linked list. If your goal is to have *top tier performance*, then pure `array list` will always beat any `linked list` implementation you can come up with. And `std::vector` is already what you should be using 99% of the time.

If you already implement a function that takes collection of elements and build `Nodes` out of them, you somewhat enforce OS to gets you chunks of memory for Nodes in kind of contiguous fashion. It's not a strong guarantee, but I would consider it good enough.

You **can't** release individual elements that belongs to a chunk of memory created with `new[]`. **If** you want to stick to array as your underlying storage for `Nodes` you have two options, as already mentioned in comments.

**Option 1)** Allocate single array for whole `list` and use indexes as your `next` and `previous` pointers in nodes. Note that it would require you to somehow handle situation when your list will be asked to hold more elements than your array can handle. Most likely allocating more arrays or allocating bigger one and copying everything which will bring you to array list with fancy ordering.

**Option 2)** Add dedicated memory manager that will be allocating chunks of memory in form of arrays and will handle individual entries, which is basically implementing your own memory `allocator`.